# Compare Active Contours Segmentation (Snake) to Level Sets Segmentation

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, image-analysis

I am reading about segmentation and I cannot seem to figure out why use active contours over level sets and vice versa. Basically the way I understood it, level sets is relatively the same segmentation method as the snake method but in a higher dimension.

What is the benefit of using one over the other?